# How to recreate a Fabric.js canvas?

Tags: javascript, json, canvas, fabricjs

I have a site where users can move images around in a Fabric.js canvas. I want to be able to recreate their "design" in a bigger canvas, so my question is; what different ways are there to recreate a canvas using the variables from the original?

Right now im using `JSON.stringify(canvas);` to get back the data, but its not really ideal since i then have to copy paste the variables again, it looks like this: `type":"image","originX":"center","originY":"center","left":135,"top":259,"`. Any suggestions on how to do this or is `JSON.stringify(canvas);` and then copy pasting all the data the simplest?

Comment: _"..but its not really ideal since i then have to copy paste the variables again"_ — what do you mean by this?

Comment: @kangax when you're not busy editing f's to F's in every fabric post, why not check answers to your own questions? Just sayin'.. :-)

Comment: @KenFyrstenberg haha, I know, I know :) Been meaning to dig into your answer but getting caught up with other stuff. Hopefully today!

Answer (score 5):

Use the `canvas.toJSON()` method to create a json object of your first canvas's objects and properties, then load that json object into your new canvas using the

`canvas.loadFromJSON("your json object");` method.

Once you have loaded the object into your canvas with the above method, call `canvas.renderAll();` and you should see the new canvas contains all the objects from the original.

You may optionally choose which properties to store in your json object by passing an array of property names to the toJSON() method, documentation can be found here :

http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#toJSON